# Writing a Script to Delete JMS Queus in Websphere

Tags: java, queue, websphere, messaging, jms

suppose I have the following JMS queues "doc/queue1","home/queue2" and "someOtherQueue" added in a websphere process server, how can I write a script to delete them? looking around the web i haven't found a solution to my problem yet unfortunately, thanks in advance for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`deleteWMQQueue`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rmj_wmq_jmswmqq_delete.html) command (for WMQ queues) and the [`deleteSIBJMSQueue`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rjn_jmsqueue_delete.html) command (for other types of queues).